# How to use splat within a function call in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, why doesn't `print(*[1,2])` work?  Doesn't it mean `print(1,2)`?

More specific to my situation:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([1,2,3,4]) % create and manipulate numpy array
print(*n.tolist()) % print results
```

If the splat function worked, my next questions would be:

1. Does it work on bumpy arrays?
2. What is the order of operations? I.e. is `tolist()` performed first, or splat?

---

... (thanks for the quick responses).  I'll accept that `print()` is not a function, but `csv.writer.writerow`?

Lets get more specific:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
n = np.array([1,2,3,4])           # create and manipulate numpy array
print(*n.tolist())                # print results
flName = 'C:\Users\Joe\test.csv'
fl = open(flName, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(fl)
writer.writerow(*n.toList())     # ERROR with splat
fl.close()
```

Now I wonder what is and is not considered a function?

Comment: "Splat" your cute name for crashing/some debugger/IDE do that?

Comment: @NickT It's the official name of the operator. Look it up, or try it out (with an actual function, of course).

Comment: If you're using Python 2, how does `print(*n.tolist())` not throw an error? Also, `writerow` takes a list of fields, so you can remove the splat and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, we're going to have to see a transcript of the output of the programme. What is the error you are experiencing?

Comment: @NickT yea, it gave me a laugh when I found out.  I always googled for "unwrap" or "split".

Comment: @Marcin Running a script through the IDLE gui, it pops up a window saying "There's an error in your program: invalid syntax", and does not compile or run.  It will compile and run just fine without the asterisk, but print the list as a string in one csv cell.

Comment: @JoeN Yes, there is a syntax error. If you run it in a proper console window, it will give you an error message pointing out the line. Please do that, and paste it into the question, so we can actually see it.

Comment: @Marcin It red-highlights the asterisk on the second to last line.  Not sure how to show that.

Comment: @JoeN Please stop using IDLE. Please run python in a console window.

Comment: @Marcin pretty sure it's not the "official name" of the expansion/(un)pack operator.  I use it and keyword expansion frequently, and never heard anyone call it a "splat".  [Google seems to agree.](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.python.org+splat) (top results are just using "Splat" as a variable name)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, not a function, so it doesn't actually take any arguments. When you "call" `print(1, 2)`, you're actually printing the tuple `(1, 2)`.

You need a function in order to unpack the arguments, so import Python 3's `print` function at the very top of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Right, but he doesn't need to unpack the arguments at all, because it's not a function.

Comment: @Marcin: Which is why I'm suggesting the `__future__` import, which turns `print` into a function.

Comment: It's unneccessary, because he doesn't need to splat at all, because it's not a function.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm not following you. The `__future__` import replaces the `print` statement with a `print` function, so argument unpacking will work.

Comment: Yes, it will work. However, there is no reason why he should switch to functional print, because he does not need to splat the list. He does not need to splat the list because print is not a function. Do you think that all programmes with splats are better than programmes without? Why do you think it is desirable to splat into a function call rather than just using print as it is?

Comment: @Marcin: Because the output of `print(n)` and `print_func(*n)` are different. You could replace it with `print ' '.join(map(str, n))`, but I don't like the way it looks.

Comment: @Blender- I've edited the question.  I was not aware that print was not a function.

Comment: @Blender Again, the difference exists because you are using the functional version. You don't need to.

Comment: @Marcin: The outputs of `print(n)` and `print(*n)` are different. You can't compare them. One prints `str(n)`, while the other prints `' '.join(map(str, n))`.

Comment: @Blender True and not in conflict with what I said.

Comment: SOLVED (thanks!):  The input to the writerow function is a single list.  I was trying to send a list consisting of a number and a list... all I had to do was add the number to the list: `writer.writerow(5+n.toList())`, not `writer.writerow((5,*n.toList()))`.  This was actually an error in how I concatenate lists.

Comment: @JoeN: Are you sure those inner parentheses? `[5] + n.tolist()` would've worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
csv.writer(fl).writerow()
```

takes a list as its argument. So,

```
writer.writerow(*n.toList())
```

will try to send each element of the list as an argument, 4 in this case.  What works is:

```
writer.writerow(n.toList())
```

However, when I tried to do:

```
writer.writerow((5,*n.toList()))
```

a syntax error was thrown.  This is not how one should do it according to "[How can I get the concatenation of two lists in Python without modifying either one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344017/how-can-i-get-the-concatenation-of-two-lists-in-python-without-modifying-either)".  The corrected version is:

```
writer.writerow([5]+n.toList())
```

for an output file that writes "5,1,2,3,4".

Answer (score 0):

It would mean `print(1,2)` if `print` were a function. It's not - it's a statement. The `(1,2)` in that case is actually just a tuple, not a function call.

In your case, you don't need to splat, because print isn't a function.

You can't splat outside of a function call.