# Python: manipulating list in place

Tags: python

As a beginner to programming I was trying to do this and that with Python. I wanted to have a simple function that takes a list as its arguments, and returns another list which is simply the original list rotated once (so `rotate([1, 2, 3])` would return `[2, 3, 1]` ), while keeping the original list unaltered.

I know that this one

```
def rotate(list):
    list.append(list[0])
    list.remove(list[0])
```

would change the list in place (and return None).

But this one

```
def rotate_2(list):
    temp = list
    temp.append(temp[0])
    temp.remove(temp[0])
    return temp
```

would also change the original list in place (while returning the desired list).

And the third one

```
def rotate_3(list):
    temp = [x for x in list]
    temp.append(temp[0])
    temp.remove(temp[0])
    return temp
```

gives the desired result, that is returning a new list while keeping the original one untouched.

I can't understand the behaviour of `rotate_2` . Why would `list` be changed when the function is just doing something on `temp` ? It gives me a feeling as if `list` and `temp` is 'linked' by `temp = list` . Also why is `rotate_3` ok? Sorry if my English is strange, it's not my first language (unlike Python).

Comment: Because `temp = list` **does not** create a copy, unlike the list comprehension in `rotate_3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `rotate_2`, `temp` and `list` refer to the same list, so when you change one, they both change.

In `rotate_3`, you are making a copy. A slightly more idiomatic way to make a copy is:

```
temp = list[:]
```

I personally would write this function as follows:

```
def rotate_4(l):
    return l[1:] + [l[0]]
```

This uses [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) and [list concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344017/how-can-i-get-the-concatenation-of-two-lists-in-python-without-modifying-either).

Note that I've renamed `list` to `l` since `list` is a [built-in name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: So as I understand that, `l = [1, 2]` creates a list in some kind of Python's Platonic universe and give a name `l`, and `temp = l` just gives another name for _that_ list, while `l[:]` makes a copy of `l` and slice it?

Comment: @LChris314: Exactly.