# Concatenating two lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, concatenation

I have a list of lists that looks as follows (I hope I'm right when I said list of lists):

```
['[175', '178', '182', '172', '167', '164]', "['b']"]
```

How can I concatenate the two lists? That is, having a list that looks as follows:

```
[175, 178, 182, 172, 167, 164, b]
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What are these `[`s in `'[175` doing?

Comment: That was a portion of the output that resulted from: X = np.array([[i[0],i[1]] for i in images])

Comment: Note that your input is not two lists. It is a list of strings.

Comment: @Simplicity: It looks like you converted the numpy array to a string. Please do not do that: you here "lose information and structure", making reconstructing the array much harder.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that that's not a list of lists, but just a list of strings that, when concatenated, might look like one or more (nested) lists, in particular with those `[` and `]` in the first and last element. Thus, you *could* join those strings with `,` to a string that actually represents a pair or tuple of lists, and then `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` those. Then just use a list comprehension to flatten that actual list of lists.

```
>>> lst = ['[175', '178', '182', '172', '167', '164]', "['b']"]

>>> ','.join(lst)
"[175,178,182,172,167,164],['b']"

>>> ast.literal_eval(','.join(lst))
([175, 178, 182, 172, 167, 164], ['b'])

>>> [x for sub in ast.literal_eval(','.join(lst)) for x in sub]
[175, 178, 182, 172, 167, 164, 'b']
```

Comment: sharpy eyes you have...

Answer (score 0):

list concatenations work with a +
so ...

```
lsts = ['[175', '178', '182', '172', '167', '164]', "['b']"]
new_lsts = []
for i in lsts:
  new_lsts += i
```

Also this similar question has been asked here many times.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344017/how-can-i-get-the-concatenation-of-two-lists-in-python-without-modifying-either)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

and probably several other times

Comment: I don't think this will connect the "items"?

Comment: it does if your lists were actually lists of lists rather than lists of strings

Answer (score -1):

In python you can use `+` to concat them:

```
a = [2,5,6]
b = [6,1,4]
c = a+b
print(c)
```

Comment: Why downvote? it just doesn't show the for loop upon the list of lists, i wanted the OP to get to it.